# How to fill remaining columns within CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I've been trying to create a responsive grid layout and almost got it. I am able to make it with this:

```
.container {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}
```

If I have 4 items in my grid, the result looks something like this:

```
=============
= 1 = 2 = 3 =
= 4 =   =   =
=============
```

The thing is that I would like the fourth cell (In this case, but could be another, depending on how much items are in my grid) to fill the remaining columns, like this:

```
=============
= 1 = 2 = 3 =
= 4 = 4 = 4 =
=============
```

I know this can be done in flex, but if it is possible, I would really like to do it with grid.

Thank you.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.grid-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No...this is not possble with CSS-Grid. Widths of grid-children have to be defined.

Comment: This is where Flexbox would be a better solution

Comment: @IvanS95 how would you solve this with flex?

Answer (score -5):

With CSS-Grid, fully automatic and responsive, it is not possible. My advice is to use Bootsrap's Grid system.
See the documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: People come to this site looking for answers, not referrals. Although your post may have some value as a comment to the question.

Comment: Developers come here to learn how to solve problems, not how to backbox its problems with a CSS framework.